# Android: take picture then display on screen

Tags: java, android

I can't for the life of me get picture to display right after taking it directly from app.

Currently, picture gets saved to gallery, doesn't display, and user has to select from gallery.

Code is below, can someone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Total Android newbie and have been stuck on this for hours! How can Android not have such a common feature be easier to implement? *sigh*

```
package com.tractable.imagegraph_dev.tractableapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean hasActiveNetworkRequest = false;

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 0;

    private NetworkUtils networkUtils = new NetworkUtils();
    private GuiToolbelt guiToolbelt = new GuiToolbelt();
    private ImageUploader imageUploader = new ImageUploader();
    private ResponseParser responseParser = new ResponseParser();
    private ImageUtils imageUtils = new ImageUtils();
    private Toolbelt toolbelt = new Toolbelt();

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Bitmap dispBitmap;
    private static double neededRatio = 1024.0 / 768.0;

    private Button choosePhotoButton;
    private Button takePhotoButton;

    private TextView textView;
    private String responseText;

    private FrameLayout progressOverlay;

    private ScrollView switchesScrollView;
    private LinearLayout switchesLayout;

    // Classifiers
    private List<String> classifierNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<Switch> switches = new ArrayList<Switch>();
    private String currentCategory = "";

    private List<RadioButton> categoryButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    private RadioButton pipeButton;
    private RadioButton carInsuranceButton;
    private RadioButton dermatologyButton;

    private Button runClassifiersButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        switchesLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SwitchesLayout);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        choosePhotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        takePhotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhotoButton);
        progressOverlay = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.overlayFrame);

        choosePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickPhoto(imageView);
            }
        });
        takePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePhoto(imageView);
            }
        });

        pipeButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pipesRadioButton);
        carInsuranceButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.carInsuranceRadioButton);
        dermatologyButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.dermatologyRadioButton);

        categoryButtons.add(pipeButton);
        categoryButtons.add(carInsuranceButton);
        categoryButtons.add(dermatologyButton);

        runClassifiersButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.runClassifiersButton);

        pipeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!hasActiveNetworkRequest) {
                    hasActiveNetworkRequest = true;
                    setupUiForCategory("pipes");
                    setImageUploadedText("");
                    pipeButton.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        });

        carInsuranceButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!hasActiveNetworkRequest) {
                    hasActiveNetworkRequest = true;
                    setupUiForCategory("cars");
                    setImageUploadedText("");
                    carInsuranceButton.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        });
        dermatologyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearClassificationData();
                setImageUploadedText("Classifier not available (currently training)");
            }
        });

        runClassifiersButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!hasActiveNetworkRequest) {
                    if (guiToolbelt.hasSelectedSwitch(switches)) {
                        progressOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        takePhotoButton.setEnabled(false);
                        choosePhotoButton.setEnabled(false);
                        uploadPhoto(imageView);
                    } else {
                        setImageUploadedText("Please select at least one classifer");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void pickPhoto(View view) {
        if (!currentCategory.equals("")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        } else if (currentCategory.equals("")) {
            setImageUploadedText("Please select a category");
        }
    }

    public void takePhoto(View view) {
        if (!currentCategory.equals("")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Take Picture"), 0);
        } else if (currentCategory.equals("")) {
            setImageUploadedText("Please select a category");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            if (networkUtils.isNetworkConnected(this.getApplicationContext())) {
                try {
                    try {
                        Uri s1 = data.getData();
                        System.out.println("-+-+-1" + s1 + "-" + data);
                        InputStream s2 = getContentResolver().openInputStream(s1);
                        System.out.println("-+-+-2");
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(s2);
                        System.out.println("-+-+-try" + bitmap.getWidth() + " " + bitmap.getHeight());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        System.out.println("-+-+-catch" + bitmap.getWidth() + " " + bitmap.getHeight());
                    }
                    int neededHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
                    if (bitmap.getHeight() > bitmap.getWidth())
                        neededHeight = (int) (bitmap.getWidth() / neededRatio);

                    int neededWidth = (int) (neededHeight * neededRatio);
                    // Setup Image Data
                    bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, neededWidth, neededHeight);
                    //dispBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);

                    //if (dispBitmap.getWidth() < dispBitmap.getHeight()) {
                    //    dispBitmap = imageUtils.rotateImage(dispBitmap);
                    //}

                    //if (dispBitmap.getWidth() > Constants.scaledImagePixels || dispBitmap.getHeight() > Constants.scaledImagePixels) {
                    //    dispBitmap = imageUtils.scaleImageWidth(dispBitmap, Constants.scaledImagePixels);
                    //} else if (dispBitmap.getHeight() < Constants.minimumImagePixels || dispBitmap.getWidth() < Constants.minimumImagePixels) {
                    //    dispBitmap = imageUtils.scaleImageWidth(dispBitmap, Constants.scaledImagePixels);
                    //}

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    runClassifiersButton.setEnabled(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    setImageUploadedText("There was an error getting the image");
                }
            } else {
                setImageUploadedText("Please connect to the internet to use the app.");
                progressOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
    }

    public void uploadPhoto(View view) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    processImageUpload();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        textView.setText("Uploading...");
    }

    public void setupUiForCategory(final String category) {
        clearClassificationData();
        setCurrentCategory(category);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    classifierNames = ClassifierDelegate.getInstance().getClassifersListForCategory(category);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        for (int i = 0; i < classifierNames.size(); i++) {
                            Switch newSwitch = new Switch(getBaseContext());

                            newSwitch.setText(classifierNames.get(i));
                            switches.add(newSwitch);

                            switchesLayout.addView(newSwitch);
                        }

                        guiToolbelt.setSwitchAsSelectedByString(switches, pipeButton.getText().toString());
                        hasActiveNetworkRequest = false;
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    private void clearClassificationData() {
        setCurrentCategory("");
        classifierNames.clear();
        guiToolbelt.setAllRadioButtions(categoryButtons, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < switches.size(); i++) {
            switches.get(i).setText("");
        }
        switches.clear();
        switchesLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    }

    public void processImageUpload() throws Exception {
        responseText = imageUploader.uploadImage(Constants.serverUrl, bitmap, getClassifiersList(), currentCategory);
        if (responseText != "") {
//            Map<String, Double> parsedResponse = responseParser.parseMapResponse(response);
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                setImageUploadedText(responseText.replace(";", "\n"));
                progressOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                takePhotoButton.setEnabled(true);
                choosePhotoButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    private List getClassifiersList() {
        List<String> classifiersList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < switches.size(); i++) {
            if (switches.get(i).isChecked()) {
                classifiersList.add(switches.get(i).getText().toString().toLowerCase().replace(" ", ""));
            }
        }

        return classifiersList;
    }

    void setImageUploadedText(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    void setCurrentCategory(String catergory) { currentCategory = catergory; }
}
```

By the way, I am writing this app strictly for a Moto 4G.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1980;



Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intentcamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intentcamera, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)
    {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        your_screenview.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

Comment: not working, but probably because I have some silly thumbnail hack in place to remove. let me just change that

Comment: There are 2 more lines code if you forget to write in your manifest which will be permission and uses feature of camera bcz I didnt write together I think you have already knewn about that right?